# MySQL joining tables gives unexpected output

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have been bashing my head against a brick wall trying to get this working and I don't know why it's not.

I join tables A and B using my_field.  I then run a sub query to get my_field from table B *where complete = 1*.  This is what I want to use to query tables C and D

This is my current query

```
SELECT 
    table_A.*,
    table_B.*,
    table_C.*,
    table_D.*
FROM table_A
    INNER JOIN table_B ON
        table_A.my_field = table_B.my_field
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT my_field FROM table_B WHERE complete ='1') test ON
        table_B.my_field = test.my_field
    RIGHT JOIN table_C ON
        test.my_field = table_C.my_field
    INNER JOIN table_D ON
        table_C.my_field = table_D.my_field
```

This is the output of the current query

```
table_A.field1  |   table_A.field2  |   table_B.field1  |   table_B.field2  |   table_C.field1  |   table_C.field2  |   table_D.field1  |   table_D.field2  |   test.complete
=============================================================================================================================================================================
something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |       1
    null        |       null        |       null        |       null        |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |       0
```

and this is what i want to get

```
table_A.field1  |   table_A.field2  |   table_B.field1  |   table_B.field2  |   table_C.field1  |   table_C.field2  |   table_D.field1  |   table_D.field2  |   test.complete
=============================================================================================================================================================================
something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |       1
something       |   something       |   something       |   something       |   null            |   null            |   null            |       null        |       0
```

UPDATE:

Here is the table structures.  I've removed columns that have do not link to any other table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_A` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_B` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `complete` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_C` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `code` (`code`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_D` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: `Left Join` and `Right Join` in the same query hurts my head...

Comment: I'm almost certain if you use memorable naming conventions things would be better .. why not use fruits and foods or cars or whatever. generic names tire me

Comment: what is the point of this code ? : : `LEFT JOIN (SELECT my_field FROM table_B WHERE complete ='1') test ON
        table_B.my_field = test.my_field`   --> why are you doing all that

Comment: can we see the structure of the tables pleaes ?

Comment: I want all rows from tables A and B and only rows from tables C and D where the complete field in table B is set to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you get rid of the Left Join?  This makes it easier to read.

```
SELECT 
  table_A.*,
  table_B.*,
  table_C.*,
  table_D.*
FROM table_A
  INNER JOIN table_B ON
    table_A.my_field = table_B.my_field
  LEFT JOIN table_C ON
    table_B.my_field = table_C.my_field and table_B.complete ='1'
  LEFT JOIN table_D ON
    table_C.my_field = table_D.my_field
```

Comment: Otherwise if you need an inner join between C and D, put them into a subquery and RIGHT-JOIN the sub query.

Comment: I still get the same output

Comment: @AdRock I took another look at your example.  using a right join means you will get rows with null values in the table_A columns, if you want no nulls, don't use the right join syntax.

Comment: @bowlturner, I want all values from table_A and I need the NULLs to be in table_C

Comment: @AdRock Then you'll need a Left Join, not a right.  Made changes above.

Comment: No problem!  Glad I could help, just needed to fully understand the problem!